# How do you get an item from a mobx observable in a reactive manner?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Let's assume there's a singleton `TodosStore` that looks something like this:

```
class TodosStore {
    @observable isLoading;
    @observable todos;

    @action.bound fetchTodos() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        return api.getTodos().then(todos => this.todos = todos)
            .finally(()=>this.isLoading=false);
    }

    getTodoById(id) {
        return this.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id);
    }
}
```

Let's also assume a single todo detail view that uses the URL for state, e.g. `/todos/123`.

```
@observer class TodoDetail extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        TodosStore.fetchTodos().then(
            this.todo = TodosStore.getTodoById(props.subscriptionId);
        );
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {TodosStore.isLoading ?
                    'Loading, please wait...' :
                    <h1>this.todo.text</h1>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So, `this.todo` is obviously not reactive, so setting it will not re-run `render()`.
One option is to create an `@observable todo;` in the view code, but I'd rather keep mobx helpers out of views.

Is there a better way for doing this, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One solution**

One way is to use React's setState method.

```
 constructor(props){
    TodosStore.fetchTodos().then({
        this.setState({ todo: TodosStore.getTodoById(props.subscriptionId) })
    });
}
```

**Second solution**

Another way would be to access (dereference) the todos in your component. That way mobx knows that this component needs to be updated, when the todos change.

```
class TodoStore {
 @observable todos = []; //initialize your todos as empty array
}

@observer class TodoDetail extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
      TodosStore.fetchTodos();
   }

   render(){
    const todo = TodoStore.todos.find(todo => todo.id === this.props.subscriptionId);
    return (
        <div>
            {TodosStore.isLoading ?
                'Loading, please wait...' :
                <h1>todo.text</h1>
            }
        </div>
    );
   }
}
```

*In this case, everytime your todos array would change, the component would try to find the todo and rerender.*

To let mobx know, that your components need to listen to changes of your observable, you must "do" something with this observable.
Either accessing a prop of the observable, or like in this case, call a method (here `todos.find()`)

**And there is also a third solution**

```
class TodoStore {
 @observable todos = []; //initialize your todos as empty array
}

@observer class TodoDetail extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
      TodosStore.fetchTodos();
   }

   render(){
    const todo = TodosStore.getTodoById(props.subscriptionId);
    return (
        <div>
            {TodosStore.isLoading ?
                'Loading, please wait...' :
                <h1>todo.text</h1>
            }
        </div>
    );
   }
}
```

Because you component now gets your todo in the render method,and your component listens for changes on the isLoading prop, your component will be called when isLoading changes.

*With this solution, your component rerenders everytime isLoading changes.*

As you see, how you access the observable object makes a difference. It depends on under what condition you want your component to rerender.

Comment: Excellent answer. Options 3 looks best. Thank you.